# ОС компилятор

Tags: компиляция

Какой компилятор использовать для создания новой ОС?

Comment: с языком, вы, стало быть, уже определились? Осталось выбрать компилятор?

Comment: @Arnold А слабо создать новую ОС, используя Visual Basic?

Comment: @alexlz Visual Basic - это еще тудым-сюдым, [вот этот чувак][1] может написать операционную систему на CSS))

[1]:http://lurkmore.to/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B#Errorov_.D0.9D.D0.B8.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.BB.D0.B0.D0.B9_.D0.9E.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.B3.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B8.D1.87

Comment: чего уж тут… давайте уже на HTML ОС мутить )

Comment: Да ладно вам. Ограничимся языками программирования. Может unlambda?

Comment: или brainfuck?

Comment: [Денис][1], ты???


  [1]: http://lurkmore.to/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81_%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: предлагаю ссылки на лурк и википедию запретить законодательно, я опять потерял два часа своей жизни случайно кликнув на одну из них.

Comment: @eicto так чем же плохо просвещаться?) Я например с большим удовольствием прочел статью о господине Бабушкине

Comment: синдром энциклопедии... я в детсве толковым словарем зачитывался...

Comment: @eicto, Вово, я пока эти ссылки оттуда копировал выпал из работы на 2 часа :(((

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопрос не показывет наличие каких-либо знаний о программировании у его автора и ответ на этот вопрос не существует.

Answer (score 3):

***Компилятор*** - это обработчик исходного кода, заранее написанного на языке программирования. На нем, Вы приложение не напишите.

***Windows***, к примеру, написан в основном на языке **C** и **C++** некоторые задачи на **Assembler**. На 7ке в ход пошла и **С#**

***Android***, ядро написано на **C** (линуксовское), а сама оболочка **Java**

Учите **С**/**С++** - не прогадаете. А если еще и **Assembler** потянете – будете большим, большим молодцом!

Answer (score 0):

Напиши на msl, будет шикарно!